# Spring reactive without using Entity class

Tags: spring, reactive

I need to expose reactive end-points i.e Flux/Mono in Spring+Java. But I
don't want to use Entity class as the definition of Entity class may keep on changing
and we can have dynamic need to register new Entity classes.

Is there any way we can implement Spring Reactive end-points without Entity class.

I am using Spring+Java and Mongodb.

Comment: "Spring Reactive end-points without Entity class" what does this mean ?

Comment: In case of Mongodb you can say Document Entity class. For example I want to fetch Employee Collection data through Spring and ReactiveMongo but don't want to define Employee Entity Class. Hope I am able to explain the problem ?

Comment: you can use Document object https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#find-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks for reply, but here EntityClass is mandatory, thats what I am looking for, is there anyway we can do without EntityClass ?

Comment: Thanks Veke, got the solution, I have posted over my response.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring framework relies on entities, whether reactive or not. It basically doesn’t affect you because you need to have knowledge of the document to reference a key value. What is not in the entity will not be set for it. If the element does not exist but the entity does, NULL is set.

If you use Kotliin, I recommend using nullable values like the "?" symbol if not guaranteed to non-null.

*Side note: How would you like to do anything if you don't know what you're storing?*

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution that as follows:
You can use ReactiveMongoTemplate. For example:

```
@Autowired
private ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public Flux<Document> findAll() {
    return mongoTemplate.findAll(Document.class,"employee");
}

public Mono<Document> save(Document data){

    return mongoTemplate.save(data,"employee");
}
```

So Instead of passing any Entity Class, you can use Document.class

Comment: Nice, thats good